# React JS button not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a React demo app and I have this component:

```
var MediaList = React.createClass({
displayName: 'MediaList',
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        tweets: getTweets(numTweets)
    };
},
render: function() {
    var tweets = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.tweets.length; i++) {
        var tweet = this.props.tweets[i];
        tweets.push({
            key: tweet.id,
            avatar: tweet.avatar,
            name: tweet.name,
            text: tweet.text,
            favorites: tweet.favorites,
            retweets: tweet.retweets
        });
    };
    return (React.DOM.div(
        React.DOM.button({
            onClick: this.
            changeAllTweets
        }, " Change all tweets "),
        React.DOM.button({
            onClick: this.
            changeRandomTweet
        }, " Change one tweet "),
        React.DOM.div({
                className: "tweets-list"
            },
            React.DOM.h2(null, tweets.length, " tweets ", React.DOM.small(null, "Update rate ", interval, " seconds")),
            React.DOM.ul({
                    className: "media-list"
                },
                this.state.tweets.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return calculateRating(b) - calculateRating(a);
                }).map(renderRow)
            )
        )
    ));
},
changeAllTweets: function() {
    var getTweetData = function() {
        var nameStart = _.random(loremLen - 12);
        return {
            avatar: "http://playground.ahrengot.com/tweets/img/" + _.random(1, 6) + ".jpg",
            name: lorem.substring(nameStart, _.random(nameStart + 5, nameStart + 12)),
            text: lorem.substring(0, _.random(90, 140)),
            favorites: _.random(0, 2000),
            retweets: _.random(0, 500)
        };
    };
    var tweets = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        var data = getTweetData();
        data.id = i;
        tweets.push(data);
    };
    this.setState({
        tweets: tweets
    });
},
changeRandomTweet: function() {
    var tweets = this.state.tweets;
    var randPosition = _.random(0, numTweets - 1);
    tweets[randPosition].favorties = _.random(0, 5000);
    tweets[randPosition].retweets = _.random(0, 1250);
    this.setState({
        tweets: tweets
    });
}});
```

What I am confused about is that one of the buttons as well as the div with tweet list inside gets rendered, but the first button(Change all tweets) isn't. What could possibly be wrong here?

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but you might find JSX easier to understand at a glance

Comment: Make yourself a favor and use JSX :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `null` as the first argument to `React.DOM.div`.

```
React.DOM.div( null,
   React.DOM.button({ ... })
```

That being said, you should look into using JSX. It will be much easier to write, read, and debug.